# Creating svg sprites using grunt module

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt and node js. I'm facing issues in creating svg sprites using grunt-svg-sprite module. I have used [grunt-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-svg-sprite#readme) module to create svg sprite image. I have installed the [grunt-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-svg-sprite#readme) module using the following command.

```
    npm install grunt-svg-sprite --save-dev
```

I enabled the plugin in my grunt.js file using the line below.

```
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svg-sprite');
```

And my plugin configuration is as follows

```
  svg_sprite                  : {
    basic                   : {

        // Target basics 
        expand              : true,
        cwd                 : 'images/svg-logo/',
        src                 : 'images/svg-logo/*.svg',
        dest                : 'out/',

        // Target options 
        options             : {
            mode            : {
                css         : {     // Activate the «css» mode 
                    render  : {
                        css : true  // Activate CSS output (with default options) 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

My folder structure is given below

```
    Project_folder
    ├───css
    ├───Images
    │   └───svg-logo
    ├───GruntFile.js
    ├───html
    ├───node_modules
    ├───include
    ├───package.json
```

When i run the following command, i get the success message, but there is no folder has created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is ok here.  src should be specify only the file there.
Try with this one.

```
    svg_sprite : {
        basic : {

            expand : true,
            cwd : 'images/svg-logo',
            src : ['**/*.svg'],
            dest : 'out',

            options : {
                mode : {
                    css : {
                        render  : {
                            css : true
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
```